# Show that $g(x) = f(x) - f(-x)$ is odd

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

How do I show following function is odd? I'm not sure whether I keep making a mistake or the function is even.

$$g(x)= f(x) - f(-x)$$

I know how to check if some functions, like $x^2, x^3$, are odd or even. For example,

$$(-x)^3 = -x^3$$

so $x^3$ is odd. But I am quite confused for this one, since the formula is not given.

Comment: The function is indeed odd. You need to show that $g(-x) = -g(x)$. Can you write out what $g(-x)$ evaluates to, and simplify that for us? (You can do this by clicking on "edit" beneath your question).

Comment: What do you think relates $g(-x)$ to $g(x)$, for general values of $x$?

Comment: Why not compare $g(-x)$ to $g(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple
$$
g\left(-x\right)=f\left(-x\right)-f\left(x\right)=-\left(f\left(x\right)-f\left(-x\right)\right)=-g\left(x\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

$g(-x)= f(-x) - f(x)=-(f(x)-f(-x))=-g(x)$